# Rock, Paper, Scissors game using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting a Rock, Paper, Scissors game using Javascript. I'm new to Javascript, so I don't know much. Each time I click a button I can get the values both for playerSelection and computerSelection but when I try to run the function playRound() it seems like it can't "reach" the values returned by clicking the buttons. What am I doing wrong?

```js
const selectionButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-selection]')
const options = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']

function computerPlay() {
 const random = options[Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length)]; 
 console.log(random)
 return random
}

function playerSelection() {
  selectionButtons.forEach(selectionButton => {
    selectionButton.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const selected = selectionButton.dataset.selection
    console.log(selected)
    return selected
    })
  })
}

function computerSelection() {
  selectionButtons.forEach(selectionButton => {
    selectionButton.addEventListener('click', e => {
    computerPlay()
    })
  })
}

const playerSelected = playerSelection()
const computerSelected = computerSelection()

function playRound() {
  if (playerSelected == 'rock' && computerSelected == 'rock' ||
      playerSelected == 'paper' && computerSelected == 'paper' ||
      playerSelected == 'scissors' && computerSelected == 'scissors') {
      console.log('tie')
  }
  else if (playerSelected == 'rock' && computerSelected == 'scissors' ||
           playerSelected == 'paper' && computerSelected == 'rock' ||
           playerSelected == 'scissors' && computerSelected == 'paper') {
           console.log('player won') 
           }
  else {
    console.log('player lose')
  }
}

playRound()
```

```css
* {
    font-style: arial;
    background-color: lightblue;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.scores {
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    justify-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 2rem;
}


.selection {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: red;
    font-size: 1rem;
    transition:500ms;
}

.selection:hover {
    transform: scale(1.3)
}

.header {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top:0;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.selections {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    margin-top: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
Choose your option:
</div>
<div class="selections">
<button class="selection" data-selection="rock">Rock</button>
<button class="selection" data-selection="paper">Paper</button>
<button class="selection" data-selection="scissors">Scissors</button>
</div>
<div class="scores">
<div>
    Player Score
    <span>0</span>
</div>
<div>
    Computer Score
    <span>0</span>      
</div>      

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your issue is that the `return` from the click event handler returns to what called it - ie the browser - ie does nothing.  Instead of thinking of "playRound" like you might in a procedural application (or console app), ie "start the round, wait for keyboard input", you need "playRound()" (or a reworking of it) *inside the click event*

Comment: Off topic: `if (playerSelected == computerSelected) { console.log('tie')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple issues here. First off, you are calling the `playRound()` function before any buttons are pressed. It's called on load of the script and then never again. What you'd need to do is to call `playRound()` inside your click handler because that is the event which you need to test if the user won, lost, or tied.

Secondly, you are trying to return values from a click handler inside a `.forEach`, neither of which by definition return a value to their caller.

I think your best bet to solve this is to do a couple things:

1. Move your `computerPlay()` into your click handler
2. Move your `playRound()` into your click handler

Here's an example of what it would look like:

```js
const selectionButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-selection]')
const options = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']

function computerPlay() {
 const random = options[Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length)]; 
 return random
}

selectionButtons.forEach(selectionButton => {
  selectionButton.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const selected = selectionButton.dataset.selection;
  const computerSelected = computerPlay();
  console.log("Player Selection: " + selected); 
  console.log("Computer Selection: " + computerSelected); 
  playRound(selected, computerSelected);
  })
})

function playRound(playerSelected, computerSelected) {
  if (playerSelected == 'rock' && computerSelected == 'rock' ||
      playerSelected == 'paper' && computerSelected == 'paper' ||
      playerSelected == 'scissors' && computerSelected == 'scissors') {
      console.log('tie')
  }
  else if (playerSelected == 'rock' && computerSelected == 'scissors' ||
           playerSelected == 'paper' && computerSelected == 'rock' ||
           playerSelected == 'scissors' && computerSelected == 'paper') {
           console.log('player won') 
           }
  else {
    console.log('player lose')
  }
}
```

```css
* {
    font-style: arial;
    background-color: lightblue;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.scores {
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    justify-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 2rem;
}


.selection {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: red;
    font-size: 1rem;
    transition:500ms;
}

.selection:hover {
    transform: scale(1.3)
}

.header {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top:0;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.selections {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    margin-top: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
Choose your option:
</div>
<div class="selections">
<button class="selection" data-selection="rock">Rock</button>
<button class="selection" data-selection="paper">Paper</button>
<button class="selection" data-selection="scissors">Scissors</button>
</div>
<div class="scores">
<div>
    Player Score
    <span>0</span>
</div>
<div>
    Computer Score
    <span>0</span>      
</div>      

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That solved my problem! Thank you very much!